# Python - Can a web server avoid imporing for every request?

Tags: python, django, import, request, nlp

I'm working on a Python project, currently using Django, which does quite a bit of NLP work in a form post process. I'm using the NLTK package, and profiling my code and experimenting I've realised that the majority of the time the code takes is performing the import process of NLTK and various other packages. My question is, is there a way I can have this server start up, do these imports and then just wait for requests, passing them to a function that uses the already imported packages? This would be much faster and less wasteful than performing such imports on every request. If anybody has any ideas to avoid importing large packages on every request, it'd be great if you could help me out!

Thanks,
Callum

Comment: How are you deploying Django? CGI, fCGI, WSGI or something else? (for other commenters: yes, you can run Django via CGI).

Comment: I'm only using the development server for now, but my intention (not heavily researched yet) is WSGI on Nginx. I'm definitely adaptable to fit this requirement though.

Comment: You should remember that Django development server autoreloads modified modules at runtime, so that you don't have to restart. Probably this is the reason why NLTK is reloaded on each request... I guess this won't happen when using WSGI...

Comment: I'm not modifying NLTK though, it's just imported. It's not getting modified between requests, but it seems that the views.py file it is in gets reloaded in full every request - including all its imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django, under most deployment mechanism, does *not* import modules for every request. Even the development server only reloads code when it changes. I don't know how you're verifying that all the imports are re-run each time, but that certainly shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was basically just comparing how my code's running locally to on localhost on Django; I'll check my code a bit more thoroughly and try to figure it out. Cheers. Do you know if Django's development server does this?