# Python Django request flow

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I would like to know does Django make import for each http user reuqest ? Example: 100 user make page request. So does it means 100 time is going import module operation in server side ?

Comment: no, the modules are imported once per process. individual requests are function calls. someone else can probably explain in more detail... in the WSGI server there are many options to configure how requests are distributed among a pool of python processes (and/or threads)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532314/python-can-a-web-server-avoid-imporing-for-every-request

Comment: To key off Anetropic's response, I have an apache server running WSGI set up for X workers; I added a couple of print statements to my settings.py and one of my models.py and after reloading apache, I see multiple prints initially and then none on subsequent requests after I've gotten each worker to do their initialization

Comment: So you mean python import modules bu first user request or by apache lunch ?